# Lemon Grass not blooming. What to do with the buds?

Tags: grass, flowering

I have this Lemon Grass grown in a pot that has produced really long stalks (7feet) with compound flowers but they haven't bloomed. It's been few months now. Will they bloom or if not, how do I know if the seeds are ready?

Location: Delhi.

[image]

[image]

[image]